# Laravel rest API middleware

Tags: rest, laravel-5

I have a rest API where a lot of routes will be prefixed by /org/{id}. This prefix will scope the nested data and also the user will need to be checked if they are a member of the org. Would middleware be the best place to run these checks and also initialise an orgcontext class that can be accessed throughout the rest of the request?

Comment: Are users typically members of more than one org?

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes. There is functionality in the front end to change which org you are working in. It is an angular spa and I am using session storage to store the current org id so the user can work in different orgs in different tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A middleware is probably the perfect place to do those checks:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Repositories\Eloquent\UserRepository;

class CanAccessOrg
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, UserRepository $userRepository)
    {
        if (! $userRepository->currentUserCanAccessOrg(Session::get('org'))) {
            Auth::logout();

            return redirect()->route('login')->withErrors(['msg', 'You dont have access to this org']);;
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```